# Problem using matlab2tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, pgfplots, plot, matlab

I'm trying to get `matlab2tikz` to work. I want to use it for prettyfying output of Matlab's `image()` command.

In Matlab I tried

```
imagesc(rand(100));
xlabel('X');
ylabel('Y');
title('Random Colors');
matlab2tikz('image.tikz');
```

but when I do

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\input{../../../../src/image.tikz}
```

it get error

```
ERROR: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/y dir' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

Also when I try the `matlab2tikz` recommended settings

```
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} % For best results
```

I get a similar error

```
ERROR: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgfplots/compat' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

How do I determine if my `pgfplots` version is too old? I'm on Ubuntu 11.10. The latest version of `pgfplots` itself is 1.5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The keys in question have been introduced in pgfplots version 1.3 . I suppose your TeX version comes with pgfplots 1.2.2 . You can inspect the actual versions on your system by looking into the .log file: in always contains the versions of every loaded package (search for 'pgfplots').

Comment: Note that the pgfplots manual contains detailed installation instructions which should allow you to upgrade to a recent version without changing the system-wide tex distribution.